# Encountering "Unable to find valid certification path to requested target" when Integrating TFS with Eclipse (Java 1.6)

Tags: java, eclipse, certificate, keytool, pkix

I am integrating TFS repository into my Eclipse but I am getting error

[image]

I used this command from CMD for installing the certificate into JVM

```
keytool -import -alias tfscer -keystore  "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP_1\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre\lib\security\cacerts"  -file "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP_1\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre\lib\security\-certificate.crt"
```

I have my certificate at the location mentioned above.

CMD returned this output

[image]

Still I cant connect to the TFS. Please help me out. Thanks in advance